# apticron EMAIL setting format for multiple recipients?

Tags: configuration, updates

What is the format for multiple emails in `/etc/apticron/apticron.conf`?

Should it be

```
EMAIL="user1@example.com" "user2@example.com"
```

or

```
EMAIL="user1@example.com user2@example.com"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EMAIL="user1@example.com user2@example.com"` is the correct format. I have tested it out and can confirm that it works.